# Redirection with strings

Tags: jquery, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect url as the following example.
I want to apply the following request to Wordpress.
Maybe its possible with jQuery (I am not sure)

My current url is http://www.example.com/category/catalog/tablets-01

And I want all urls that contains "**/category/catalog/**"
To change to to this http://www.example.com/catalog/?_category=tablets-01

Even if the url is this: www. example .com/category/catalog/tablets-01/apple-new/
Should change to: www. example .com/catalog/?_category=apple-new

Thank You !

Comment: I am trying for permanent redirect such we are speaking for main menu.
I want actually to auto-redirect wp categories to plugin "given" urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$a=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos($a,'/category/catalog/'))
{
str_replace("/category/catalog/","/catalog/?_category=",$a);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location=\''.$a.'\';</script>';
}
?>
```

**You can use this pHp code to redirect to your desired page**

Comment: Thank you @Ayush Jain AJ
Where I should place this code ?
To functions.php ?

Comment: You can save this code in functions.php and then use"<? include_once ("functions.php");?> in the pages where you want to perform this redirection